# Check if contains in sub-classes

Tags: java

What I'm trying to accomplish is set the #example field to the current example sub-class instance wrapped in an optional, if the contains returns false on all sub-classes i'd like to return an Optional#empty

I have an abstract class.

```
public abstract class Example {

public abstract boolean contains();

}
```

I then have some sub-classes.

```
public final class Example1 extends Example {

@Override
public boolean contains() {
return true;
}

}

public final class Example2 extends Example {

@Override
public boolean contains() {
return true;
}

}
```

and I have a field to determine what example currently is present.

```
private final Optional<Example> example;
```

is there a way to loop through the sub-classes and return the #contains condition?

something like

```
Optional<Class> clazz = Some sort of loop to check if the #contains condition returns true;
```

then set my example field

```
if(clazz.isPresent()) {
setExample((Example) clazz.get());
}
```

this is all pseudo-code, this will not work. If you guys know how to do this and could explain me that'd mean a lot :)

Comment: Can you further explain what you're asking when you say "is there a way to loop through the sub-classes and return the #contains condition"?

What do you mean by loop through the sub-classes? Each object of type Example is either an Example1 or Example2, not both.

Comment: It sounds like you have confused classes with instances.  You would not “loop through the sub-classes”;  you would loop through an array or Collection or Stream of instances.

Comment: Each class only has one implementation of `contains()` to call.

Comment: @Jason Qlueses : Are you saying you don't know how many of the implementing "sub-classes" there is in advance? Because if that is the case, you can probably use a design patter like Publish–subscribe.

Comment: @GregHilston I don't want to store instances of the classes in a collection. I'm trying to use reflection to check if the contains returns true on any of the sub-classes and return an instance of that class.

Comment: @JasonQlueses This is the first time you mentioned you're using reflection. Perhaps you could edit your original question, as it appears no one is understanding your question. Please clarify, as reflection shouldn't  be used to check a return value.

Comment: @GregHilston I assume reflection was the only way to do something like this, if there is another way **without** storing the class instances in a collection, i'd like to try that out too.

Comment: @JasonQlueses Again, as I mentioned in my previous comment "Perhaps you could edit your original question, as it appears no one is understanding your question." I am **still** not aware of what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @JasonQlueses Thank you! I believe I understand your question. Please see my answer

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question, but it seems like you are asking a standard inheritance question.

Say I have a list of examples. Set example to the first one for which contains() returns true:

```
List<Example> examples = Arrays.asList(new Example1(), new Example2(), ...);
for (Example ex: examples) {
    if (ex.contains()) {
        example = ex;
        break;
    }
}
```

If this is not what you were asking for, maybe try to clarify your question a bit more.

Comment: I don't want to store instances of the classes in a collection, but what you're doing is exactly what i'm looking for. I'm trying to use reflection to check if the contains returns true on any of the sub-classes and return an instance of that class.

Answer (score 0):

*It depends on the use-case.* For singleton, enumeratable (listable) instances use an **enum**, where every enum constant can override.

```
public enum Example {
    EXAMPLE1() {

        @Override
        public abstract boolean contains() {
            return true;
        }
    },
    EXAMPLE2() {
        ...
    },
    EXAMPLE3() {
        ...
    };

    public abstract boolean contains();
}
```

Or in java 8 pass a function to the constructor:

```
public enum Example {
    EXAMPLE1(() -> true),
    EXAMPLE2(() -> false),
    EXAMPLE3(() -> System.currentMillis() % 2 == 0);

    private final Supplier<Boolean> cont;

    private Example(Supplier<Boolean> cont) {
        this.cont = cont;
    }   

    public boolean contains() {
        return cont.get();
    }
}
```

Comment: Not looking into using an enumerated type, I never knew you could use suppliers like that though, thanks for that :)

Answer (score 0):

Jason and I had a discussion in the comments section of his question.

Jason, I believe you are describing the functionality that is solved the use of the Decorator pattern.

Essentially, you'll have a required object of the class, which in your provided example is called "Example". The other classes that you called "Example1" and "Example2" become the decorators, or optional wrappers on the required object of the class.

I believe this answers your question and is what known as a design pattern.

A good tutorial is here:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/decorator_pattern.htm

Comment: Uhm, i'm not sure how I would retrieve the #contains of any of the sub-classes and set that class instance as my field.